# Puppet on Windows failing silently

Tags: windows-server-2008, puppet

None of my newly added Windows Puppet nodes seem to work, though none give errors.  My Linux nodes work fine.  I tried this line below in my nodes.pp, and a puppet kick runs without error, but does nothing (other Linux boxes in the same nodes.pp do what they should).  `C:\test` exists.

```
node 'my-winserver.mydomain.org' {
  file { 'C:\test\Puppet_Works':
    ensure => present
}
```

And I tried this by opening the "Open Puppet with Command Prompt" option from the Puppet directory in the Start menu and tried this:

```
puppet apply -e "file { 'C:\PuppetFile': ensure => present}"
```

again, it fails silently, no errors, just doesn't do squat.  The box shows up on the Puppet Master in a `cert list --all`.  U see plenty of GETs and PUTs in the PuppetMaster log for this Windows box.  **Puppet 2.7 (Win client 2.7.23) Master OS RHEL 5 server, Win Client OS Server 2003,2008**

Comment: Please add the output of `puppet apply -e "file { 'C:\PuppetFile': ensure => present}" -dv`.

Answer (score 0):

Like Felix mentions, the best way to see what it going on is to add `--debug --verbose --trace` to the end of the run. It's hard to know what's happening without this information.

**Update:** `ensure => file` OR `ensure=> directory` NOT `ensure => present`

I think a possible factor here is that you are using a much older version of puppet that had early support for Windows. Many of the issues you are going to run into have been fixed in the newer versions.

The support for Windows has fundamentally improved since 2.7.x. You should really be looking to get to Puppet 3.4.x+ with Windows.

Here's the closed issues for Windows:

- http://bit.ly/puppet_windows_closed_old_tracker (old Redmine issues tracker)
- http://bit.ly/puppet_windows_closed (new Jira issues tracker)

Comment: isn't ensure => present the same as ensure => file?  It's always worked for me.  http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#file-attribute-ensure

Comment: If it is failing silently on that version of Puppet with Windows (something that hasn't worked for you at all yet based on your OP), then perhaps you should explore using it.

Comment: And you are looking at the docs based on the latest version. Which you are not using. ;)

Comment: Note that http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/2.7.latest/type.html#file even mentions you can use present, but again we are talking about early support for Windows so you might want to be more explicit. The reason? It looks like you are specifying directories because you don't also have `content => 'some content',` and in windows, file types usually have extensions.